# SQL*Plus error logging truncate does not work

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

My scripts use [SQL*Plus error logging](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2698945) to track errors during installation.
The scripts start like this - they enable erorr logging and truncate any existing entries:

```
SQL> set errorlogging on truncate
SQL> select * from table_does_not_exist;
select * from table_does_not_exist
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Then at the very end I query `sperrorlog` to see what went wrong:

```
SQL> select statement from sperrorlog;

STATEMENT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select * from table_does_not_exist
```

But every now and then the `truncate` does not work, and I get errors from previous installations.  Why doesn't `truncate` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite it's name, SQL*Plus error logging truncate does not actually truncate the table.  It deletes the data and does not commit.

This SQL*Plus session enables error logging and creates an error.  Another call to enable errorlogging and truncate does clear out the data, but the rollback undoes the truncate.

```
SQL> set errorlogging on truncate
SQL> select * from table_does_not_exist;
select * from table_does_not_exist
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> set errorlogging on truncate
SQL> select statement from sperrorlog;

no rows selected

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select statement from sperrorlog;

STATEMENT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select * from table_does_not_exist

SQL>
```

To be safe, you should always issue a `commit` right after `set errorlogging on truncate`.

Comment: I know it's been an year this question was asked. But, I think  I have another solution. Why not use a `global temporary table` for `sperrorlog` and make it `on commit delete rows`. And, regarding the rollback thing, it is a bigger issue with the error logging itself. This might be helpful http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/sqlplus-error-logging-workaround-for-rollback-issue/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, those are some good ideas.  Error logging is a good idea, it's a shame how horribly they botched such a simple thing.

Comment: I hope Oracle would fix the stupid issues or come up with some robust logic. Being one of the guys in there, I know how less important it is for the dev team. Entire focus is just on expanding the enterprise products, least importance is for the database products and its features :-( unfortunately, it is a fact.

Answer (score 0):

> To be safe, you should always issue a commit right after set errorlogging on truncate

Or, do an **explicit TRUNCATE** which would do an **implicit commit** being DDL statement. Of course, this is just like not using the `truncate` option, however, so is the problem with the `rollback`. I found the workaround for the rollback issue and shared it in my blog [SQL*Plus error logging – workaround for ROLLBACK issue](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/sqlplus-error-logging-workaround-for-rollback-issue/)

Coming back to your issue, I am trusting more on an explicit truncate:

```
SQL> set errorlogging on
SQL> select * from table_does_not_exist;
select * from table_does_not_exist
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select statement from sperrorlog;

STATEMENT
----------------------------------------
select * from table_does_not_exist

SQL> truncate table sperrorlog;

Table truncated.

SQL> select statement from sperrorlog;

no rows selected

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select statement from sperrorlog;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Alternatively, you could use **global temporary table** for **`sperrorlog`** table and make it **`on commit delete rows`**.